# how to use ReferenceManyField?

Tags: react-admin

target property of **ReferenceManyField** doesn't run using **react-admin**.
I respected the logic given in the documentation. I even made sure that my data provided has id without subtracks because I use a database **mongo db** (where the identifiers have this form _id). In short ReferenceManyField returns all data to me without regard to target property

```
export const HistoryHospitalListTest = props => (
  <List title="Liste des Hôpitaux" {...props}>
    <Datagrid>
      <TextField source="id" />
      <TextField source="slug" label="Years" />
      <ReferenceManyField
        reference="historyHospitals"
        source="projectKey"
        label="2019"
        perPage={7}
        allowEmpty={true}
      >
        <SingleFieldList>
          <ChipField source="slug" />
        </SingleFieldList>
      </ReferenceManyField>
      <EditButton />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```

Comment: What does the API request sent by your browser for the ReferenceManyField look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I had found the solution since several
First use target instead of source.
Second, point the resource to the appropriate route (the one linked to the main route here is hospitals).
Note that ReferenceManyField is basically used to connect a main road with other roads via a common property (for my case it is projectKey, which is the primary key of an occurrence of hospitals)
Make sure the API returns ids like this id and not _id
Once all of the above are checked, our final code will look like this:

```
    export const HistoryHospitalListTest = props => (
  <List title="Liste des Hôpitaux" {...props}>
    <Datagrid>
      <TextField source="id" />
      <TextField source="slug" label="Years" />
      <ReferenceManyField
        reference="historyHospitals"
        target="projectKey"
        label="2019"
        perPage={7}
        allowEmpty={true}
      >
        <SingleFieldList>
          <ChipField source="slug" />
        </SingleFieldList>
      </ReferenceManyField>
      <EditButton />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```